# ADT version not upgrading

Tags: android

I was trying to upgrad my adt version to 23 but it shows following error..I do not how to solve it can any one help me with this...

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.4.1468518       (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.4.1468518)
Software currently installed: Android Development Tools 22.0.0.v201305140200--675183 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.0.0.v201305140200--675183)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
ADT XML Overlay 23.0.4.1468518 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.4.1468518)
ADT XML Overlay 22.0.0.v201305140200--675183 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 22.0.0.v201305140200--675183)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Android Development Tools 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.4.1468518)
To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.4.1468518]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Android Development Tools 22.0.0.v201305140200--675183 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.0.0.v201305140200--675183)
  To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [22.0.0.v201305140200--675183]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Help > Install New Software
Work with: p2repo - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
Select Developer Tools and Next
Next, Accept the license agreement* and Finish
```

either try If you have a conflict with the previous version:

1. Select Help > Install New Software
2. Click on already installed
3. Select all Android software on version 22.*
4. Click on Uninstall
5. Work with: dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse
6. Select Developer Tools and Next
7. Next, Accept the license agreement and Finish

Comment: yet not working still showing errors @Eddie

Comment: Select Developer Tools and Next :: It shows error on 1st Next:: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

On Unisntalling: An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.win32.win32.x86_64 1.0.0.M20130204-1200 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).

Comment: what problem you facing?

Comment: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.4.1468518)